# Not a duplicate - xampp not defaulting to index.php5, can I configure this?

Tags: php, xampp

xampp (on Windows) is working when I have an index.html or index.php file. I am using .php5 as an extension for new files in the project, and would like to use index.php5 for consistency. It is not a big deal, but my syntax highlighter is set up to color .php files differently, so I am reminded that they are older.

Can I configure xampp to use index.php5?

This is not a duplicate of the other question. The other question is about parsing and running .php5 files in general. This is not a problem on localhost and it is not a problem on any of servers I have running on goDaddy, rackspace and bluehost. The problem is specific to index.php5 - it parses and runs properly when the full name is typed in, but it is not recognized as the default when no file name is entered.

Can I configure xampp to DEFAULT to index.php5 given that php5 is working?

Comment: You can, but what happens when you want to move code to another server maybe a hosted server? Stick to a standard file extension or it will cause you issues later

Comment: Thanks Jeff and RiggsFolly, but for anyone stumbling on this in the future - php5 is in fact a standard file extension for PHP 5.